# .Net core 6: How to have output directory without assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-core, build, assemblies, project-properties

I am porting company products in .Net core 6 from .Net 4.8.
In the solution, there is an output directory containing:
Assemblies, Configuration, Log, Resources directories and only .exe, .pdb and .exe.config of the launcher project.
Dlls are in Assemblies directory and I absolutely need to replicate the same structure.

In launcher project .csproj file we have set:

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
```

In others:

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\$(Configuration)\Assemblies</OutputPath>
```

During compilation, VS Studio Professional 2022 continues to copy .dlls/.pdbs of the ProjectReference included projects and recursively it copies all the .dlls more and less.
In order to avoid this behavior, I have tried a lot of methods, such as using all these properties (also in different setting combinations: none, all, compile...) but the issue still happens:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
<CopyLocal>
<CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>
<IncludeAssets>
<ExcludeAssets>
<PrivateAssets>
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
```

At the moment, I am building in windows but in the future there will also be some linux machines that have to build solutions, so I need a method that should work in all environments.

Is it possible to do it?

Loading of assemblies is not a problem, I have modified AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving and if I manually delete dlls from the output directory, the application works but I need something more "elegant" than a delete script after building (Post-build event).

Answer (score 0):

When you mention "a delete script after building", was that implying one called using a Post-build event? I realize this is probably not exactly what you had in mind, as it will in effect be a script that is called after each time a project is built.

Still, it's not exactly the same as running a script manually, so if you are having trouble finding better options, this may be an alternative?

Open **Properties** for your project, and look for this:
(*You may also want to have a look at [the documentation for build evens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022)*)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately when I said "a delete script after building", I meant Post-build event. So I am looking for another solution, your suggestion was my last option.